# PCduino - NFC/RFID HSU

Tags: c++, linux

i need some assistance to try and get a NFC/RFID reader working on Ubuntu on a pcduino

since i am using `HSU` (*high speed UART*) and the `SDA` and `SCL`  pins i have found that on PCDUINO v2 there are dedicated pins for this at the very end of the Arduino pin header.

Doing `sudo i2cdetect -y 2` I found out that the device shows up on `0x24` so from there I am now trying to work out a way of reading the data.

I have found this:

- http://i.got.nothing.to/hack/on/run-the-sl030-rfid-reader-on-linux/

using the C code from there that I have copied, and using the g++ command i tried to compile that code with no luck.

It shows an error at compilation ; I get the follow error message:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/Documents# g++ RFID.CPP -o RFID
RFID.CPP: In function \u2018int main()\u2019:
RFID.CPP:57:22: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
RFID.CPP:79:22: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
```

so at the moment i am stuck on this

- http://elinux.org/Interfacing_with_I2C_Devices#Completed_Code

reading through that article I may be able to use the following command to debug, but I have no idea how:

```
$ i2cdetect -r 2
```

any help will be great :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that your web browser added some UTF-8 characters in your code, which is weird because that character is not present in the code:

- [U+2018](http://www.charbase.com/2018-unicode-left-single-quotation-mark) being `‘` ;
- [U+2019](http://www.charbase.com/2019-unicode-right-single-quotation-mark) being `’` (no, it's not the same! ;-) )

I just made a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/guyzmo/10118958) that I doubled check against weird characters that you can [download](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guyzmo/10118958/raw/bbc8ec3611c82adb71f55c524cda9a92529b9563/i2c_scanner.c).

Finally, as I'm explaining in the blog post, and as is explained on elinux:

```
i2cdetect -r 2
```

will list all the addresses and connected devices on those addresses, as shown in my blog post. Then you can access a given device by using the `i2cget` command, if that device is using a register based protocol, which pretty standard amongst i2c devices, but the `SL030` device I wrote about in my article is an exception!

```
i2cget <device address> <register in device>
```

basically, you shall first read your device's datasheet to see how to communicate with it, and then you'll know how to communicate with... whether you can do it in shell using `i2cget` or you need to use something like the code I've hacked.

N.B.: I'm the writer on http://i.got.nothing.to/blog/